# Jquery disappearing div issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please refer this fiddle  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrikanth/V7uc7/3/)

I wanted to have following requirements here.

click event of div 'bbb' should display another div 'aaa' ------ Working

while focussing variuos textbox within div 'aaa' should NOT disappear div 'aaa' ----  working

if user click on anywhere else(other than div 'aaa' and div 'bbb') div'aaa' should be disappear------  Not working at this point of time

Please advise me on final requirement.

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bbb").click(function () {
        $('#aaa').show();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if ((!$(e.target).is('#aaa')) && (!$(target).is('#bbb'))) {
            $('#aaa').hide();
        }
    });
    $("#aaa input").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$(target)` to `$(e.target)` like,

```
if ((!$(e.target).is('#aaa')) && (!$(e.target).is('#bbb'))) {
   $('#aaa').hide();
}
```

No need to add `click event` on `#bbb` try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if($(e.target).is('#bbb')) {
            $('#aaa').show();
        }
        if ((!$(e.target).is('#aaa')) && (!$(e.target).is('#bbb'))) {
            $('#aaa').hide();
        }
    });
    $("#aaa input").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/V7uc7/5/)

Comment: Cool , it is working now..Thanks Rohan Kumar. I'm new to this technology . So please provide some url to understand on this piece especially target and e.target s.stopPropation

Comment: you will get all properties and functions by using `console` like `console.log(e);`, and everything is available on google.com, so you can search what you want.

Comment: Thanks I got to know some useful info on this.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(e.target)` instead of `e.target` for your second condition. You can also remove some redundant parentheses `(` and `)` inside your condition:

```
if(!$(e.target).is('#aaa') && !$(e.target).is('#bbb'))   {
// -----                         ^ here you need to use $(e.target) not $(target)
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V7uc7/4/

Answer (score 0):

**>     hi friends please remove this**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if((!$(e.target).is('#aaa')) && ( !$(target).is('#bbb')))   {
        $('#aaa').hide();
    }
});
```

> ```
> **& add this code**
> ```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if((!$(e.target).is('#aaa')) && ( !$(e.target).is('#bbb')))   {
        $('#aaa').hide();
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle_demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V7uc7/8/)